# phpliteadmin cant find sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite

I installed sqlite3 using `sudo apt-get install sqlite3`.  I also installed phpliteadmin in the `var/www` folder. When I go on phpliteadmin, it says it cant find sqlite3 and sqlite3database. How do I fix this? sqlite3 works fine in terminal.

Comment: Ok then reinstall the sqllite database and everything about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve the problem:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

The problem is you have PDO, but not the SQLite PDO driver installed.

Update: Since Ubuntu 16.04, you need the PHP 7 instead of the PHP 5 package:

```
apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Source: https://bitbucket.org/phpliteadmin/public/wiki/Installation

Comment: I did the same miss with mysql...

Answer (score 0):

you can find `phpliteadmin.php` in the `/var/www/` where you have extracted phpliteadmin . edit it with either `gedit` or `nano` text editor.

Then try to set the database path manually. Then set `$directory` to False.at The `$databases` set the path to your current sqllite databases .

answer from : http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/wiki/Installation

Comment: i did, but it says There was a problem setting up your database, o. An attempt will be made to find out what's going on so you can fix the problem more easily.

Checking supported SQLite PHP extensions...

PDO: installed
SQLite3: not installed
SQLiteDatabase: not installed

...done.

The problem cannot be diagnosed properly. Please file an issue report at http://code.google.com/p/phpliteadmin/issues/list.